# How to install opencv on raspberrypi 4 with python3.7

Tags: opencv, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

everyone,

The default version of python on the Raspberry Pi 4 is 3.9. I need python 3.7. I successfully install python 3.7.4 and set it as default by adding the line alias python3='python3.7' to the bashcr file. Then I install opencv using pip3. I got: from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libImath-2_2.so.23: cannot open a shared object file: No such file or directory

I also installed it from the source and got the same result.
I investigated and found out that I need to install libilmbase12, but I got the following error message.
E: The package libilmbase12 could not be found

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way. I change raspbian from bullseye to buster. Everything works fine. The problem was the compatibility of python and opencv version

Answer (score -1):

You install OpenCV from bash :

`sudo apt install python3-opencv`

Comment: I have already tried this. the same error.

Comment: In this way the openCv works with python3.9 not 3.7